# How do I get all subclass properties based on name

Tags: c#, class, generics, xml-deserialization

I have the following structure:

```
 public class A
 {
    public A1Type A1 { get; set; }
    public A2Type A2 { get; set; }
    public A3Type A3 { get; set; }
  }

  public A1Type
  {
    public string B1 { get; set; }
    public string B2 { get; set; }
  }
```

And similar with `A1Type` is also `A2Type` and `A3Type`. I have a more complex structure.

I receive a string parameter `A1Type` and I need to get from `A` just the subclass `A1Type` with its values.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: To avoid using reflection or high maintenance mapping, have you consider using a `Dictionary<string, object>` or `Dictionary<string, ABaseType>`. You can then just return A["A1Type"] for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A()
        {
            A1 = new A1Type() { B1 = "A1Type B1 prop value", B2 = "A1Type B2 prop value" },
            A2 = new A2Type() { B1 = "A2type B1 prop value", B2 = "A2Type B2 prop value" },
            A3 = new A3Type() { B1 = "A3Type B1 prop value", B2 = "A3Type B2 prop value" }
        };
        ListPropertyValuesOf("A1Type", a);
        ListPropertyValuesOf("A2Type", a);
        ListPropertyValuesOf("A3Type", a);
    }

    static void ListPropertyValuesOf(string propName, A classA)
    {
        // get all properties of classA object
        var props = classA.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.Name == propName)
            {
                // get the specific sub-type object on classA
                var subClassA = classA.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(classA);

                // loop each of the properties on subClassA and write its value
                foreach (var subProp in subClassA.GetType().GetProperties())
                    Console.WriteLine(subProp.GetValue(subClassA));
            }
        }
    }
}

public class A
{
    public A1Type A1 { get; set; }
    public A2Type A2 { get; set; }
    public A3Type A3 { get; set; }
}
public class A1Type
{
    public string B1 { get; set; }
    public string B2 { get; set; }
}

public class A2Type
{
    public string B1 { get; set; }
    public string B2 { get; set; }
}

public class A3Type
{
    public string B1 { get; set; }
    public string B2 { get; set; }
}
```